# jQuery Scrollbar Plugin that shows bar and offers function only if there is an overflow

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a small jQuery plugin, which shows a scrollbar next to a box with an overflow, something like this:

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
(1st example)

The Problem:
The scrollbar shall only be shown if there is a real overflow. If the content fits the parent, no scrollbar shall be shown. The jQuery Mousewheel Plugin should be supported, too.

Does somebody know a jQuery Scroll Plugin, which has this function?

Comment: Do you know that the linked plugin always shows the scrollbar even if the content is **not** larger than the height?

Comment: I assume you want the stylized scrollbar, not the default provided by your browser when you specify overflow:auto, right?

Comment: @marcus Yeah, I think that's what he's trying to get around.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, I know. this is it, what I want to avoid. The scrollbra shall only be shown, if there is something to scroll @ehudokai: YEP

Comment: Maybe I should have worded that... "have you tested it to ensure it doesn't do what you want". But anyway, this quick google revealed a [top 10 list](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plugin you specified.  Just add a check around it like the following

```
if($("#yourContent").height() > $("#yourViewport").height()){
    $("#scrollbar1").tinyscrollbar();
}
```

That way it only turns on if you need it.

Hope that helps!